# Progress Bar While Creating Database

Tags: android

I know that this has been asked before but I have a different setup.

My Sqlite Database:

```
private void SetUpLibrary() {
     ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Declare SQLiteDatabase object
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

        try {
            //Instantiate sampleDB object
            sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(db.dbname, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            //Create table using execSQL

            try{
                //add table
                sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + db.tblnames[0]+  " (disease_no INTEGER, disease_name VARCHAR, disease_desc VARCHAR, disease_symptoms VARCHAR, disease_control VARCHAR);");


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application library has been set successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (SQLiteException se ) {
               }

        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't create or open the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

And my Progress bar:

```
  progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

      // Start long running operation in a background thread
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 30) {
               progressStatus += 1;
        // Update the progress bar and display the 
                             //current value in the text view
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
          // textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
        }
            });
            try {
               // Sleep for 200 milliseconds. 
                             //Just to display the progress slowly
               Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
      }).start();
```

And here's the XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bStart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="30"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:progress="1" />
```

I wanna ask how to make progress bar work while setting up the SQLite Database. I have tried some suggestions but none of them worked.

Comment: Please don't use max 30 ever again 0 to 100 so you can deal with percent completion.  That is unless you have something that has an actual value of 30 like days in September, April, June, and November.

Comment: With what exactly you have a problem? You don't see a progress going by on progress bar? Give some details about a handler you use in `handler.post(new Runnable() {...}`.

Comment: @danny117: yes yes, sorry about the 30. it should be 100.

Comment: I just want the progress bar to work while the processing a method and ends when the process is finished. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the progress from the setup.  See below

```
private void SetUpLibrary() {
     progressBar.setProgress(0);

     ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Declare SQLiteDatabase object
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

        try {
            //Instantiate sampleDB object
            sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(db.dbname, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            progressBar.setProgress(50);
            //Create table using execSQL

             try{
                //add table
                sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + db.tblnames[0]+  " (disease_no INTEGER, disease_name VARCHAR, disease_desc VARCHAR, disease_symptoms VARCHAR, disease_control VARCHAR);");

                progressBar.setProgress(100);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application library has been set successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (SQLiteException se ) {
               }

        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't create or open the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.Gone);
}
```